# Open or download Zip File From Other Drive using PHP

Tags: php

I want to open or download on Chrome / Mozilla Browser zip file from other drive using PHP backend. Location of Zip file is `P:\niks\all Zip Files\Reports\Report 01 feb 2019.zip`.

```
$filePath = 'P:\niks\all Zip Files\Reports\Report 01 feb 2019.zip';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filePath) . "\";");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filePath);
```

After running this script The Zip file will get downloaded in the download folder but it wont open. and I am getting below error.

[image: Error Prompt.]

I didn't got any answer after google search.

Comment: Please consider reading some tutorials on the matter, and provide code examples of what you've already tried to implement.

Comment: so you would like to use PHP, which runs on the webserver, to download(?) a file on your computer - the `P` drive?

Comment: file is located in P drive. I wan to download or directly open it from P drive.  it will be helpful if there is any other way to achieve this using web browser.

Answer (score 0):

It may occur if you are mixing HTML with PHP or your PHP script may contains white space after closing tag `?>` that means something is being send to the browser along your zip content. So open your ZIP file in your text editor and see what is at the beginning of the file, compare with correct ZIP archive and then look where you can escape this character. And try to :

1- Remove the closing tag `?>` and let just the open tag `<?php`.
2- Add this function **[ob_end_clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)** at the top of your PHP script.

```
<?php
     ob_end_clean();
     $filePath = 'P:\niks\all Zip Files\Reports\Report 01 feb 2019.zip';
     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filePath) . "\";");
     header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
     readfile($filePath);
```

Comment: This didn't work. getting same error pop up every time.

Comment: Try to add `ob_start();` on the top  and `ob_end_clean();` at the end, look at the php doc : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

Comment: This is also not working.
Is this issue occurring because the zip file is located in another drive of the Computer ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an incorrect content-type:

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
```

should be

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
```

or

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

otherwise, the file transfer may be interpreted by the browser as a non-binary transfer (read: text) and the file may get downloaded incorrectly

Comment: Hi  Javier, This solution is also not helpful as I am getting same error. is there any other way to achieve this ? means by Jquery or using bach files ?